# How do I config BIND to serve an address app.domain.domain

Tags: bind

I want to to serve a web application at app-name.local.dev

Currently I have the configuration ready to serve it at app-name.local

name.conf

```
zone "davinci.local" IN {
    type master;
    file "davinci.local";
};
```

davinci.local

```
davinci.local. 7200    IN       SOA     davinci.local. root.davinci.local. (
          20100601 ;    Serial (a date in this case)
          15      ; Refresh every 15 minutes
            3600    ; Retry every hour
            3000000 ; Expire after a month+
            86400 ) ; Minimum ttl of 1 day
              IN      NS      davinci.local.
              IN      A       127.0.0.1
*.davinci.local.        IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

What changes do I have to do in order to serve  davinci.local.dev ?

I try this: 
name.conf

```
zone "davinci.local.dev" IN {
   type master;
   file "davinci.local.dev";
};
```

/var/named/davinci.local.dev

```
davinci.local.dev 7200    IN       SOA     davinci.local.dev. root.davinci.local.dev. (
          20100601 ;    Serial (a date in this case)
          15      ; Refresh every 15 minutes
            3600    ; Retry every hour
            3000000 ; Expire after a month+
            86400 ) ; Minimum ttl of 1 day
              IN      NS      davinci.local.dev
              IN      A       127.0.0.1
*.davinci.local.dev        IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

But I get this error:

```
named-checkzone davinci.local.dev /var/named/davinci.local.dev 
/var/named/davinci.local.dev:1: SOA record not at top of zone (davinci.local.dev.davinci.local.dev)
/var/named/davinci.local.dev:8: using RFC1035 TTL semantics
zone davinci.local.dev/IN: loading from master file /var/named/davinci.local.dev failed: not at top of zone
```

In nginx.conf:

```
server {
      listen 8080;
      server_name .davinci.local;
      root /Users/Nerian/NetBeansProjects/DaVinci/DaVinci/public;
      passenger_enabled on;
   }      

server {
      listen 8080;
      server_name .davinci.local.dev;
      root /Users/Nerian/NetBeansProjects/DaVinci/DaVinci/public;
      passenger_enabled on;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another section to `named.conf`:-

```
zone "davinci.local.dev" IN {
    type master;
    file "davinci.local.dev";
};
```

Then, take a copy of the zonefile for `davinci.local`, change all references to `davinci.local.` to `davinci.local.dev.`, and save as `davinci.local.dev`. You'll then need to tell bind to reload its config - `rndc reload`, `service bind reload` or `/etc/init.d/bind reload` should work, depending on the operating system.

You'll also need to make changes to your webserver - presumably another virtualhost.

Comment: I try doing that. But I get an error. I added the error message to the Question.

Comment: Try adding a period to the end of the `zone` line, so it reads `zone "davinci.local.dev." IN {`. You're also missing a `.` after `davinci.local.dev` at the very beginning of the zone file.

Comment: ...oops, and `*.davinci.local.dev` should read `*.davinci.local.dev.` - with a period at the end.